# Post multidimensional array (string[][]) in angular using HttpClient / HttpParams

Tags: angular, http, post, multidimensional-array, parameters

I'm having trouble finding guidance on the best-practice way to do this with angular (2+). Angular's HttpClient's [post function](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) has an [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) parameter. HttpParams is a key/value map of type `[param: string]: string | string[]`. But, I need to post a multidimensional array (2D) parameter (`string[][]`). i.e.

```
this.http.post(url, {}, {
    params: {
        2d: [ [ 'arr1' ], [ 'arr2' ] ]
    }
});
```

But this does not seem to be supported by angular's HttpParams class. While searching around other questions, I found out that

- [this is possible in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162136/how-to-post-array-multidimensional-angular-js) using the same `Content-Type` that angular uses (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).
- [this is possible without a framework in vanilla js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578344/how-2d-array-is-handled-in-http-post-request), but you must encode your multidimensional array on the client side

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to do this in angular. If there is not, why did angular make this design decision and what is a workaround?

Comment: do you really need to pass that matrix as query params? why not send it in the request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jota.Toledo, @David and this question on ["Is there any difference between using request.body or request.params",](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187424/is-there-any-difference-between-using-request-body-or-request-params-in-node-js)
 my main misunderstanding was trying to use HttpParams for everything and ignoring the request body. The best solution to my problem is to simply pass the multidimensional array in the **request body**.

**This is the "best-practice" way for a few reasons**

- The request body doesn't have any restrictions on the complexity of the data ([type "any" in the angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post))
- Using the body doesn't encode the data in the url, this avoids a potential status 414 (Request-URI Too Long) if too much data is passed
- Following a RESTful pattern, you generally use params for GET requests and the body for POST requests ([Stack Overflow question source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187424/is-there-any-difference-between-using-request-body-or-request-params-in-node-js))

Answer (score 1):

Can you just send it as a json array?

```
let data= [
    ["string1","string2"],
    ["string3", "string4"]
 ];


let body= {
 content: data
};

this.http.post(url, body)
```